# Scraping Instagram Lists with selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

IM trying to **scrape** lists from Instagram, in this case, the following list and the follower's list on my own Instagram profile. When I execute the code it logs in successfully, gets the first list (following list) successfully too but then the follower's list always stops at user 121 when being appended into an array.
Could someone help me understand why the list stops being appended, please?
I've tried switching timings and making the selenium scroll twice as much however it doesn't resolve the issue at hand, thank you.

Main.py

```
#imports
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import func
import re

#setting up and loading the browser
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users\tuxo9\Downloads\geckodriver\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")

#log in
username = "input username here"
password = "input password here"
func.login(username, password, driver)

#navigate to following list

#more efficient way of obtaining users following page
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/" + username)


following = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[3]/a")
following.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(5)


followingList = []
quantityFollowing = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[3]/a/span").text
print(quantityFollowing)
scrollbar = driver.find_element_by_class_name("isgrP")


func.createUserList(driver, quantityFollowing, scrollbar, followingList)

followersList = []
followersQuantity = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[2]/a/span").text
followersQuantity = re.sub(",", "", followersQuantity) # error due to having comma, make function to check this and remove it
print(followersQuantity)
followers = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[2]/a")
followers.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
scrollbar = driver.find_element_by_class_name("isgrP")

func.createUserList(driver, followersQuantity, scrollbar, followersList)

print(followingList)
print(len(followingList))
print(quantityFollowing)
print(followersList)
```

func.py

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import func

def login (username, password, driver):
    #accept cookie button has been pressed
    cookie  = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/button[1]")
    cookie.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    #username and password details have been entered
    time.sleep(5)
    user = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
    pwb = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
    submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div/div[3]/button")
    user.clear()
    user.send_keys(username)
    pwb.clear()
    pwb.send_keys(password)
    submit.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    time.sleep(3)

    #check if details worked

    #This finds the error message and uses 'elements' to store elements in array but there should only be one
    check = driver.find_elements_by_id("slfErrorAlert") 
    
    #checks if the error element is there and acts on it
    if check == []:
        print("success")
    else:
        print("Details are incorrect!")
        driver.close()

def createUserList(driver, quantity, scrollbar, list):
    z = 1
    y = 12

    while len(list) != int(quantity):
        if y > int(quantity):
            y = int(quantity) + 1

        if z > y:
            z = y - 2

        scrollbar.send_keys(Keys.END)
        time.sleep(3)


        for x in range(z, y):
            name = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("li.wo9IH:nth-child("+ str(x) +") > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1)")
            user = name.get_attribute("title")
            print(user)
            list.append(user)
        

        z = z + 11
        y = y + 11
```

Answer (score 0):

In `func.py` import `from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException` then use the `try` and `except NoSuchElementException` to test if the element is present, if not present which is the error it scrolls and makes the element needed to appear.
example:

```
for x in range(z, y):
    try:
       driver.find_element_by_css_selector("li.wo9IH:nth-child("+ str(x) +") > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1)")
except NoSuchElementException:
       scrollbar.send_keys(Keys.END)
       time.sleep(3)
```